# Am getting 'Variable '$data' expected value of type 'UserCreateInput!'' when attempting Prisma GraphQL 'createUser'

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server, prisma, prisma-graphql

I did a couple of sites with GraphQL-Yoga and Prisma a little while ago and am attempting the same with Apollo Express.  All worked fine.  Now however I can't get the thing started -- perhaps I'm going too fast and attempting too many things at once.  I am starting trying to implement a registration mutation following [this](https://www.prisma.io/tutorials/authentication-in-apollo-server-ct21) guide.  My first (and for the moment only) mutation is

```
const resolvers = {
  Mutation: {
    register: async (parent, { username, password }, ctx, info) => {
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10)
      const user = await ctx.prisma.createUser({
        username,
        password: hashedPassword,
      })
      return user
    },
  },
}
```

but when I test it in GraphQL Playground

```
mutation {
 register(username:"foo",password: "bar") {
  id
  username
}
}
```

I get this error

```
"errors": [
    {
      "message": "Variable '$data' expected value of type 'UserCreateInput!' but got: {\"username\":\"sandor\",\"password\":\"$2a$10$S7IF1L3YjS4dLUm8QB2zjenPnKHwlohml7AaPf1iVhNipHSkNb/62\"}. Reason: 'name' Expected non-null value, found null. (line 1, column 11):\nmutation ($data: UserCreateInput!) {\n          ^",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "register"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
```

I looked in `generated/prisma-client/prisma-schema´ and see that I have

```
  createUser(data: UserCreateInput!): User!
```

But when I used Prisma before it never complained about expecting an input type when I passed it an object.  Where am I going wrong here?

My schema is

```
const { gql } = require('apollo-server-express');


const typeDefs = gql`

  type User {
    id: ID!
    username: String!
    password: String!
  }

  type Query {
    currentUser: User!
  }

  type Mutation {
    register(username: String!, password: String!): User!
    login(username: String!, password: String!): LoginResponse!
  }

  type LoginResponse {
    id: ID!
    token: String
    user: User
  }

`
module.exports = typeDefs
```

and my datamodel.prisma is

```
type User {
  id: ID! @id
  name: String!
    password: String!

}


type LoginResponse {
     id: ID! @id
    token: String
    user: User
}
```

I am sure I'm missing something blindingly obvious, but after looking some time I don't see it -- so any clue would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer -- hinted at by @Errorname in a comment and given to me by a user on the Prisma Spectrum forum (I didn't see it myself), is that there was a discrepancy between the Prisma datamodel and the GraphQL schema.  To wit, the field was being called 'username' in the schema, and 'name' in the datamodel.  I changed it to 'username' in the datamodel.  Doh!

```
type User {
  id: ID! @id
  username: String!
  password: String!
}
```

and it works fine!  I didn't need to add the 'data' object to createUser, as suggested by @Errorname above -- that is, this works fine

```
 Mutation: {
    register: async (parent, {username, password}, ctx, info) => {
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10)
      const user = await ctx.prisma.createUser({

          username,
          password: hashedPassword,

      })
      return user
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

The `createUser` method of Prisma client needs a single object arguments, which then contains the different objects required by Prisma.

The correct way to call the method is like this:

```
const user = await ctx.prisma.createUser({
  data: {
    username,
    password: hashedPassword,
  }
})
```

This way of structuring the arguments help ensure consistency with other queries:

E.g.:

```
const user = await ctx.prisma.updateUser({
  where: {
    name: "John Doe"
  },
  data: {
    password: newPassword
  }
})
```

---

Moreover, the error says: "Reason: 'name' Expected non-null value, found null." but you only give `username` and `password`. Did you forget to pass the `name` value ?

Comment: Thanks -- I changed it as you suggested to the following but am still getting the same error.   `Mutation: {
    register: async (parent, {username, password}, ctx, info) => {
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10)
      const user = await ctx.prisma.createUser({
        data: {
          username,
          password: hashedPassword,
        }
      })
      return user
    },
  },
}`

Comment: When I put the following mutation into the playground: `mutation {
 register(username:"foo",password: "barr") {
  id
  username
}
`

Comment: Hmm, the error says: "Reason: 'name' Expected non-null value, found null." but you only give username and password. Did you forget to pass the name value ?